# how to use pagecontrol globally?

Tags: iphone, uipagecontrol

In my application i want to use instance of pagecontrol in more then 3 views..so,i want to declare,@property and @synthesize should be in appDelegate..Please give some ideas to do this...

Thanks,
Mano

Answer (score 0):

I never used pagecontrol, but in principle, your code would look like:

in YourAppDelegate .h

```
@interface YourAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    ...
    UIPageControl *pageControl;
    ...
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ScrollingViewController *viewController;
```

YourAppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init]; // or whatever is needed to set up pagecontrol
}
```

in one of your views:

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//and then access the variable by appDelegate.variable
```